# CSS - keyframes transform scale of the background image only

Tags: html, css, animation

I would like to achieve the effect of the zooming in on the backround image like it is done [here](https://www.netflix.com/).

I have a div that takes up the whole page. There I have a full screen background image. I need to make the image zoom in and out, or to move from left to right, I tried that with using `keyframes` it is the first time I am using them so I am not sure how to achieve an effect of zooming in on background image. With my code all the elements in the div get zoomed in and out as well, not just the background image. How can I avoid that and have just background image zoom in and without zooming out and effecting other elements on the page?

This is my css:

```
#app {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('/img/cover.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center center;
  animation: zoom 30s infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
  50% { transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
  100% {
      transform:scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="app">

    <div id="main-section">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="drawer">
      <div id="item-detail">
      </div>
      <div id="item-detail-carousel">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns content">
      content ..
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
body {
    min-height:100%
}
#app {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.background {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: zoom 30s infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom {
    0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
    50% { transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
    100% { transform:scale(1,1); }
}
```

And HTML :

```
<div id="app">
    <img class="background" alt="Bg" src="image-surce.jpg"/>
    <div id="main-section">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="drawer">
      <div id="item-detail">
      </div>
      <div id="item-detail-carousel">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns content">
      content ..
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a better way, you use an image tag and put it as a background using your css skills and then you can apply zoom to the image. So it shows the desired effect.

Comment: But then none of the elements that are inside of main-section are not visible

Comment: Give z-index:1 to your main-section and drawer class.